# Does the Heisenberg uncertainty principle hold up for events in the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was watching this youtube video on predicting the future if you can know the exact position and momentum of every particle in the whole universe. But you can't ever know that says Heisenberg. But what about the past? If you could theoretically take a moment in the past and look at an event, say a chemical reaction, atom by atom, would you be able to know the exact position and momentum for every particle that was in that reaction because you knew the outcome?

Comment: That answer is bad...

Comment: Your argument is circular because "knowing the outcome" implies a violation of the uncertainty principle.

Comment: I wouldn't say its "my argument" as I'm asking the question. It seems their is no good answer for this